# Python No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc svd_n_s

Tags: python

I am trying to find the variance inflation factor (VIF) of a dataset using `statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence_variance_inflation_factor`. I ran the code for a dataset of completely categorical variables and it returned the VIF matrix. However when I ran the code for a different dataset I keep getting a Type error. This dataset has numerical variables. Kindly help. Please find the code below:

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor as vif
full_data = full_data.drop(response, axis=1)
data_columns = full_data.columns
out = pd.DataFrame()
Variable_name = []
VIF = []
for col_name in data_columns:
    index = full_data.columns.get_loc(col_name)
    print index
    data = full_data.as_matrix()
    Variable_name.append(col_name)
    VIF.append(np.array(vif(data, index), dtype=float))
out['Variable_name'] = Variable_name
out['Variance Inflation Factor'] = VIF
```

it works for a dataset like this
    a   b   c
    1   1   1
    1   2   2
    1   1   3
    1   1   4
    2   1   5
but not for something like this                                                                                                            -42.1585     14.7353         3.45338            4.67938 -19.0982            -17.0384    -60.3472         3.45338            4.67938 -19.0982           -42.1585    -5.62736         3.45338            4.67938 -19.0982            -17.0384    -98.0905         3.45338            4.67938 -19.0982
-17.0384    -5.62736         3.45338            4.67938 -19.0982

Comment: You could add possible working sets and not working sets if possible. Other than that good luck with your question and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I have added a sample dataset!